# how to get macid and mobile number only in android mobile device not in database

Tags: android

how to get macid and mobile number only  in android mobile device  not in database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String MACAddress = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
```