# how to get MacID of mobiledevice in android?

Tags: android

how to get MacID  of mobiledevice in android?

Comment: What's up with all the duplicate questions recently?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189569/how-to-get-macid-and-mobile-number-only-in-android-mobile-device-not-in-databas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String MACAddress = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
```